# Can a female medical professional examine the Awarah of a Non-Mahram?

Tags: halal-haram, human-body, awrah

Is it permissible to be examined by a female medical practitioner who is a non Mahram in order to seek medical advice?

The doctor may need to examine the re-productive organs.

Comment: A qualified doctor can analyze the semen without having the need to look at your penis. Unless, you  specifically had mentioned that something is wrong with it which changes the whole narrative and may require either a physical exam or a medical test.

Comment: I strongly suggest you -if you are seriously interested in answers- to become a registred user instead of spaming the site with your bawdly pseudo questions.

Comment: maybe her male friend/coworker can look at your penis and tell her it is ok

Answer (score 0):

salaam... it is totally permissible. the basic concept in islam is... whatever you do must have a niat in the name of Allah. If your niat of showing penis is for seeking medical attention and the lady doctor's niat to see your penis is for treatment, there is nothing wrong in it as long as the purpose is genuine. Allah knows better.

Comment: -1 for lack of references. You need to backup your answer with references.